# REACT: Translator Component | Setting & Accessing State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component, react-state-management, react-state

I'm working on creating a REACT component that "translates" a number by essentially taking the user's input and accessing the translation with simple key value pairs. Everything works except for my handleTranslate method. Console log for this method is giving me undefined.

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: '',
      one: 'uno',
      two: 'dos',
      three: 'tres',
      four: 'cuatro',
      five: 'cinco',
      six: 'seis',
      seven: 'siete',
      eight: 'ocho',
      nine: 'nueve',
      ten: 'diez',
      answer: ''
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleTranslate = this.handleTranslate.bind(this);
  };
  
  handleChange(state) {
    this.setState({
      input: event.target.value
    });
  }
  handleTranslate (state) {
    var x = state.input;
    this.setState({
      answer: state.x
    });
  }
  
  render () {
  return(
  <div>
      <h3>Enter an English number between one and ten and watch the translation render below</h3>
      <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange, this.handleTranslate}/>
      <p>{this.state.input}</p>
  </div>
  );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent/>, document.getElementById('view'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='view' />
```

Comment: BTW Once the method is fixed or combined with handleChange I will have to change what's inside my <p> tags.

Comment: Here is a link to one of my pens that operates in a similar fashion that does work: https://codepen.io/adamjschork/pen/QWbPeOV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one handled function with `event` would be fine

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: "",
      one: "uno",
      two: "dos",
      three: "tres",
      four: "cuatro",
      five: "cinco",
      six: "seis",
      seven: "siete",
      eight: "ocho",
      nine: "nueve",
      ten: "diez",
      answer: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      input: event.target.value
    });
    this.setState({
      answer: this.state[event.target.value]
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>
          Enter an English number between one and ten and watch the translation
          render below
        </h3>
        <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <p>{this.state.input}</p>
        <p>{this.state.answer}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you!